# npm install ошибка

Tags: npm

скачал gulp сборку для вёрстки.
Ввожу npm install, выводит ошибку
Понятия не имею что с этим делать, пробовал переустановить node, не помогло.
Проблема возникла после переустановки винды.
Даже не знаю что еще могу сказать) Заранее спасибо

```
$ npm install
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! The git reference could not be found
    npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects checkout 4.0
    npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\komen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-02T18_53_12_092Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Покажите package.json

Comment: Кажется, что npm не может взаимодействовать с гитом. Можно попробовать проверить, что git установлен и с гитхаба, к примеру, репозитории локально клонируются